# Multimarkdown in GitHub's Atom editor - made a start, want to make more progress

Tags: atom-editor, multimarkdown

To extend the basic Markdown support in Atom, I've converted the TextMate Multimarkdown bundle (unescaping one hash sign - [see the process on this Atom discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-a-package-for-multimarkdown-support-e-g-tables-definition-lists/18241)). The (converted) TextMate bundle files are now in my Atom config folder.

Markdown syntax now highlights okay (and differently from the built-in GitHub Markdown) when I choose 'Multimarkdown' from the syntax list. The table sytnax *appears* to pick out table heads, but there's no preview and no support for definition lists.

Can someone point me to the file(s) in Atom I'd need to work on to get:

1. a preview pane?
2. syntax highlighting for definition lists?

Comment: I see you posted this about six months ago. Did you ever get anywhere?

Comment: Dan - no, mainly because I'm interested more in a universal plain-text format from which PDFs, websites and other outputs can be generated from a single source, and Denis Defreyne (Nanoc) is developing D*mark, which looks like it does the job: https://github.com/ddfreyne/d-mark BUT MMD features in Atom would still be good.

Comment: I also got totally disoriented and discouraged after trying to locate, edit and test the necessary files in Atom, despite spending a weekend trying.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Maybe this bounty will motivate someone to do it, otherwise at some point I'll probably carve out time to try it myself.

Comment: Perhaps post back here if you do? I'll do the same. Penney's MMD is a much more complex beast and MD, though, with footnotes and the like, so quite a challenge… but the basics (especially DLs) would be good, which was my original aim.

Comment: I'm now using VSCode, where there's an MMD extension by André Fischer which doesn't seem to add any functionality, and the preview shows no difference. So this remains an unsolved issue!

Comment: Small world... I am also now using VSCode ;)